# Which galaxies in Super Mario Galaxy 2 are borrowed from previous Mario games?

Tags: super-mario-galaxy-2

I've noticed some of the galaxies seem to be from previous Mario games - Honeyhop (Super Mario Galaxy), Throwback (Super Mario 64) and Twisty Trials (Super Mario Sunshine) Galaxies. Are there any other galaxies that have been reused?

Specifically, please list all galaxies, and which Mario game they come from.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are the levels that are directly based on previous levels:

- [Topman's Tower](http://www.mariowiki.com/Space_Storm_Galaxy#Topman.27s_Tower), in the Space Storm Galaxy, is based on part of [Buoy Base Galaxy](http://www.mariowiki.com/Buoy_Base_Galaxy) from Super Mario Galaxy.
- [Throwback Galaxy](http://www.mariowiki.com/Throwback_Galaxy) is based on [Whomp's Fortress](http://www.mariowiki.com/Whomp%27s_Fortress) from Super Mario 64.
- [Mario Squared Galaxy](http://www.mariowiki.com/Mario_Squared_Galaxy) is based on part of [Toy Time Galaxy](http://www.mariowiki.com/Toy_Time_Galaxy) from Super Mario Galaxy.
- [Twisty Trials Galaxy](http://www.mariowiki.com/Twisty_Trials_Galaxy) is based on [The Secret of Ricco Tower](http://www.mariowiki.com/Ricco_Harbor#Episode_4:_The_Secret_of_Ricco_Tower) mission in the Ricco Harbor level of Super Mario Sunshine.
- [Stone Cyclone Galaxy](http://www.mariowiki.com/Stone_Cyclone_Galaxy) is based on the [Cyclone Stone](http://www.mariowiki.com/Beach_Bowl_Galaxy#The_Cyclone_Stone) mission in Beach Bowl Galaxy of Super Mario Galaxy.
- [Boss Blitz Galaxy](http://www.mariowiki.com/Boss_Blitz_Galaxy) features five bosses from Super Mario Galaxy.

There are also some that are more loosely inspired by previous levels:

- [Supermassive Galaxy](http://www.mariowiki.com/Supermassive_Galaxy) is similar to [Big Island](http://www.mariowiki.com/Big_Island) from Super Mario Bros. 3.
- [Flip-Swap Galaxy](http://www.mariowiki.com/Flip-Swap_Galaxy) bears some resemblance to the [Secret of the Dirty Lake](http://www.mariowiki.com/Bianco_Hills#Episode_6:_The_Secret_of_the_Dirty_Lake) mission in the Bianco Hills level of Super Mario Sunshine
- The [Tall Trunk's Big Slide](http://www.mariowiki.com/Tall_Trunk_Galaxy#Tall_Trunk.27s_Big_Slide) mission in Tall Trunk Galaxy is similar to slide levels in many 3D Mario games, and features a remix of the theme from [Princess's Secret Slide](http://www.mariowiki.com/The_Princess%27s_Secret_Slide) from Super Mario 64.
- [Starshine Beach Galaxy](http://www.mariowiki.com/Starshine_Beach_Galaxy) features many elements from Super Mario Sunshine: Piantas inhabit on the island, there is a statue similar to the one from Delfino Plaza, the island is *slightly* dolphin-shaped, and even the name "starshine" seems to be a reference to "sunshine".
- The Gearmo challenges in [Rightside Down Galaxy](http://www.mariowiki.com/Rightside_Down_Galaxy) and [Upside Dizzy Galaxy](http://www.mariowiki.com/Upside_Dizzy_Galaxy) are similar to the Gearmo challenges in [Battlerock Galaxy](http://www.mariowiki.com/Battlerock_Galaxy) and [Dreadnought Galaxy](http://www.mariowiki.com/Dreadnought_Galaxy) from Super Mario Galaxy. (In the first game, you cleaned up trash by throwing Bob-Ombs; in the second game, you use a fire flower.)
- [Honeyhop Galaxy](http://www.mariowiki.com/Honeyhop_Galaxy) features many elements similar to [Honeyhive Galaxy](http://www.mariowiki.com/Honeyhive_Galaxy) from Super Mario Galaxy, but the level geometry is actually quite different.

<sub>I'm marking this community wiki. Feel free to add to this answer!</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I Believe Stone Cyclone Galaxy is reused from Super Mario Galaxy One, though I don't know what it was called. Edit: Cyclone Stone from Beachbowl Galaxy

The Boss Blitz Galaxy as well is a mashup of boss fights from the original Galaxy as well.

Answer (score 2):

[Throwback Galaxy](http://guides.ign.com/guides/14354736/page_105.html) in World 6 is from Super Mario 64.

Answer (score 1):

The [Supermassive Galaxy](http://www.mariowiki.com/Supermassive_Galaxy) is reminiscent of [Big Island](http://www.mariowiki.com/Big_Island) from Super Mario Bros 3